# Python library for handling linux's audit.log?

Tags: python, linux, audit

I'm searching for a python (3^) library to ease the processing of audit.log (on CentOS6 that is at /var/log/audit/audit.log). I'm thinking about a library that grabs the log lines to python and enables the querying/filtering in a human way.

There are traces of a tool called [audit-python](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2006-May/msg00174.html), not in pip list, doesn't really look promising. So far no hope of a library handling this widespread audit log.

Maybe some would share their code of how they did process the audit.log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I didn't found a library nor did anyone suggest one, so I have come up with this function using a binary provided by the audit's package:

```
def read_audit(before,now,user):
    auparam = " -sc EXECVE"
    cmd = "ausearch -ts " + before.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + " -te " + now.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + " -ua " + user + auparam
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    res = p.stdout.read().decode()
    return res
```

I call the binary by the subprocess module, so an `import subprocess` is needed in the header of the code. The function grabs logs of program executions between the provided times via the `ausearch` tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package: `setroubleshoot-server`

Then look at the file `/bin/sealert` which is a python program and does a lot of stuff with `audit.log` based on the flags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have installed that utility but it took around 10 dependencies to install it and if I should rely on calling a binary I find the tool `ausearch` that comes with audit to better fit my needs.

Comment: this should be the correct solution.   It is standards compliant and doesn't offer up exec caps, which obviously are beyond me without reading, but are probably a security risk.