# How would I automatically parse the syntax of a audit.log file I open before reading actual lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, subprocess, audit-trail

I'm trying to automatically parse a log file I initially open in my Python program so that its output is in a human-readable format before I go to begin reading actual lines from the file itself. How would I do this?

```
with open('/var/log/audit/audit.log') as audit_raw:
    audit_formatted=subprocess.call(["ausearch", "-i", audit_raw])
    line = audit_formatted.readline()
```

Error message when I try exactly that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./email_script.py", line 29, in <module>
    audit_log=subprocess.call(["ausearch", "-i", audit_raw])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: So essentially when I go to actually process the line to display it in some format, I would then call the 'ausearch' program with parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call [ausearch](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch) with the correct params and parse *its* output.

Stolen here: [Python library for handling linux's audit.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916777/python-library-for-handling-linuxs-audit-log) (which is an offtopic question asking for library endorsement) and might vanish from SO - that is why I decided against "duping".

[obeliksz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956161/7505395):

> ```
> import subprocess
>
> def read_audit(before,now,user):
>     auparam = " -sc EXECVE"
>     cmd = "ausearch -ts " + before.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + " -te " + now.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + " -ua " + user + auparam
>     p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>     res = p.stdout.read().decode()
>     return res
> ```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working because I get prompted that the 'ausearch -i' option is not needed or an open parenthesis is an unexpected syntax.

Comment: Solved the issue. Ausearch -i does not need a file location to work.